# iTunes very slow since library moved to NAS drive

Tags: macos, itunes

I am running iTunes 12 on a Mac Mini (OSX El Capitan).  Previously I was using a USB external drive to hold my library.  I have upgraded to a Synology NAS drive with RAID so that I have redundancy in the disks.

My iTunes library has now moved onto the NAS.  Since I did this iTunes is running very slow.  It takes around 20 minutes just to open, hangs frequently and is slow to update the metadata on music files.

The Mac Mini and Synology NAS are connected to the same router using a Gigabit ethernet connection. I store the iTunes ITL file on the local drive (SSD).  I have a mapped network share from the Mac to the NAS using SMB (which I find to be more reliable than AFP).

Any ideas how I can speed it up?  Surely Gigabit ethernet speeds are faster than USB 3?

Comment: Is you Synology set to go to sleep?

Comment: USB 3.0 has theoretical transfer rates of 5 Gb/s. USB 3.1 does double that. *Gigabit* Ethernet well… is five to ten times *slower*. But I think it's a latency issue, e.g., the hard drive going to sleep mode.

Comment: Synology discs do sleep after 20 minutes.  I don't think this is it though, I will give an example to demonstrate why.  Yesterday I add an album with over 100 tracks, it starts adding tracks straight away, but slowly.  Each track goes in slowly.  If it was sleeping discs, then only the first item would be slow as it would speed up once the NAS was awake.